# postgresql 10 - standby flips to read/write

Tags: replication, postgresql-10, standby

I am trying to setup a primary/standby for failover; however, the standby flips to read/write and no longer functions as a replication database after the copy from the primary.  Additionally, the recovery.conf does not turn to recovery.done.

Here are my configuration files:

**Master Server Configurations**:

pg_hba.conf - added the line:

```
host replication replication_user 0.0.0.0/0 trust
```

postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
max_wal_senders = 10
port = 5432
wal_keep_segments = 500
wal_level = replica
```

**Slave Server Configurations:**

postgresql.conf:

```
hot_standby = on
```

recovery.conf:

`standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'user=replication_user password=replication_pass port=5432 sslmode=prefer sslcompression=1 krbsrvname=postgres target_session_attrs=any host=pgmaster application_name=node2 connect_timeout=2'
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
primary_slot_name = repmgr_slot_2`

The log file shows that the standby is copied properly, but then flips to not be in readonly:

```
2018-09-21 16:48:09.990 UTC [153] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2018-09-21 16:48:09.990 UTC [153] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2018-09-21 16:48:10.003 UTC [153] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2018-09-21 16:48:10.029 UTC [161] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2018-09-21 16:48:09 UTC
2018-09-21 16:48:10.214 UTC [161] LOG:  entering standby mode
2018-09-21 16:48:10.223 UTC [161] LOG:  redo starts at 0/2000028
2018-09-21 16:48:10.228 UTC [161] LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/20000F8
2018-09-21 16:48:10.229 UTC [153] LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
2018-09-21 16:48:10.238 UTC [165] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 0/3000000 on timeline 1
>>> Cloning is done
>>>>>> WAL id: 000000010000000000000003
>>>>>> WAL_RECEIVER_FLAG=1!
>>> Not in recovery state (anymore)
>>> Waiting for local postgres server start...
>>> Wait schema replication_db.public on pgslave1:5432(user: replication_user,password: *******), will try 9 times with delay 10 seconds (TIMEOUT=90)
>>>>>> Schema replication_db.public exists on host pgslave1:5432!
>>> Unregister the node if it was done before
DELETE 0
>>> Registering node with role standby
INFO: connecting to standby database
INFO: connecting to master database
INFO: retrieving node list for cluster 'pg_cluster'
INFO: registering the standby
[REPMGR EVENT] Node id: 2; Event type: standby_register; Success [1|0]: 1; Time: 2018-09-21 16:48:40.143418+00;  Details:
INFO: standby registration complete
NOTICE: standby node correctly registered for cluster pg_cluster with id 2 (conninfo: user=replication_user password=replication_pass host=pgslave1 dbname=replication_db port=5432 connect_timeout=2)
 Locking standby (NEW_UPSTREAM_NODE_ID=1)...
>>> Starting repmgr daemon...
[2018-09-21 16:48:40] [NOTICE] looking for configuration file in current directory
[2018-09-21 16:48:40] [NOTICE] looking for configuration file in /etc
[2018-09-21 16:48:40] [NOTICE] configuration file found at: /etc/repmgr.conf
[2018-09-21 16:48:40] [INFO] connecting to database 'user=replication_user password=replication_pass host=pgslave1 dbname=replication_db port=5432 connect_timeout=2'
[2018-09-21 16:48:40] [INFO] connected to database, checking its state
[2018-09-21 16:48:40] [INFO] connecting to master node of cluster 'pg_cluster'
[2018-09-21 16:48:40] [INFO] retrieving node list for cluster 'pg_cluster'
[2018-09-21 16:48:40] [INFO] checking role of cluster node '1'
[2018-09-21 16:48:40] [INFO] checking cluster configuration with schema 'repmgr_pg_cluster'
[2018-09-21 16:48:40] [INFO] checking node 2 in cluster 'pg_cluster'
[2018-09-21 16:48:40] [INFO] reloading configuration file
[2018-09-21 16:48:40] [INFO] configuration has not changed
[2018-09-21 16:48:40] [INFO] starting continuous standby node monitoring
```

I am also using pgpool and I think it looks to be correct:

```
root@5f05159b998d:/etc# gosu postgres repmgr cluster show
INFO: connecting to database
Role      | Name  | Upstream | Connection String
----------+-------|----------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* master  | node1 |          | user=replication_user password=replication_pass host=pgmaster dbname=replication_db port=5432 connect_timeout=2
  standby | node2 | node1    | user=replication_user password=replication_pass host=pgslave1 dbname=replication_db port=5432 connect_timeout=2
```

and

```
root@0d95e8dc83f8:/# pcp_attach_node -U pcp_user -h localhost -n 0
Password:
pcp_attach_node -- Command Successful
root@0d95e8dc83f8:/# PGPASSWORD=$CHECK_PASSWORD psql -U $CHECK_USER -h localhost template1 -c "show pool_nodes"
 node_id | hostname | port | status | lb_weight |  role   | select_cnt | load_balance_node | replication_delay
---------+----------+------+--------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------
 0       | pgmaster | 5432 | up     | 0.500000  | primary | 0          | true              | 0
 1       | pgslave1 | 5432 | up     | 0.500000  | standby | 0          | false             | 0
(2 rows)
```

I think either the original postgresql.conf file is being run when the standby is coming up or it is something in the pg_hba.conf but I cannot figure this out.

I am attempting to build this in docker from the postdock/postgres latest image, just to make it more complicated, but I can overwrite whatever may need to be done.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Pete